# Passing the this to a callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my Java Script object.

```
HelloObject(server) {
    this.server = server;
    this.socketio = require("socket.io");
}

HelloObject.prototype = {
    constructor: HelloObject,
    listen: function() {
        this.serverProcess = this.socketio.listen(this.server);
        this.serverProcess.sockets.on('connection', this.connect);
    },
    connect: function(socket) {

    }
}

// I am invoking the object

var socketServer = new HelloObject(server)
// Meaning "this" will refer to sockerServer
socketServer.listen()
```

Sorry for asking possibly a silly question I am new at javascript.
I need to pass "this" to the this.connect function.
I have tried this.connect.apply(this) and what ends up happening is I lose the socket object.

Comment: Either a closure or bind will work.  In some cases (but not yours) you can set `this` when calling a function with `Function.apply(thisObject, argumentsArray)` which is attached to all functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the callback, if you want the `connect` to be bound to the current object(`this`), then you need to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function, like this

```
this.serverProcess.sockets.on('connection', this.connect.bind(this));
```

Comment: Assume that I have another parameter that I want to pass, as well as "this", how would I achieve that?

Comment: @MikeChung You mean, you want to pass another parameter to `connect`? You can simply do `this.connect.bind(this, parameter)`. When `connect` is invoked, `parameter` will be the first argument to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript closure for this:

```
var $this = this;
this.serverProcess.sockets.on('connection',function () {
    $this.connect();
});
```